# I am not able to add strace package to core-image-minimal?

Tags: yocto

I am new to yocto. I am trying to add "strace" package to core-image-minimal using INSTALL_IMAGE_append = " strace" variable in conf/local.life, after executing bitbake -k core-image-minimal the image is building successfully but i am able to find strace in bin or usr/bin directory. Please tell me the what mistake i have done.

Comment: Did you put it into `conf/local.conf`? If you did, could you see if strace was being built while running bitbake? You could also run `bitbake -e core-image-minimal | grep "^IMAGE_INSTALL"` to verify that strace was actually added. Your way should work.

Comment: Yes i have put into conf/local.conf. when i run bitbake -e core-image-minimal | grep "^IMAGE_INSTALL"  it is showing IMAGE_INSTALL="packagegroup-core-boot rpm-postinsts strace "

Comment: Ok, so strace seems to be included in `IMAGE_INSTALL`. Are you sure that strace isn't installed into your image? Double check under `tmp/work/<machine>/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/bin`, it should be there unless you get some errors while running bitbake. I've just double checked this in the fido-branch.

Comment: Thanks Anders . Finally i am able to see strace in /usr/bin